# Stop Knockout on error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How do I alert an error to the user when knockout fails?
Instead of just silently doint this in the console:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this article i belive is that what you want: [Knockout catching errors](http://brianmhunt.github.io/articles/knockout-catching-errors/),
But see the snippet too, maybe give to you some idea:

```
var ErrorHandlingBindingProvider = function() {
    var original = new ko.bindingProvider(); 
        //determine if an element has any bindings
    this.nodeHasBindings = original.nodeHasBindings;
    //return the bindings given a node and the bindingContext
    this.getBindings = function(node, bindingContext) {
        var result;
        try {
            result = original.getBindings(node, bindingContext);
        }
        catch (e) {
            //here you will do what you you want to do to show to user
            if (console && console.log) {
                console.log("Error in binding: " + e.message);   
            }
        }   
        return result;
    };
};

ko.bindingProvider.instance = new ErrorHandlingBindingProvider();
```

> snippet by  : [RP Niemeyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594420/rp-niemeyer)

Comment: Great - though it will not catch a wrong template name for instance :(
@rp-niemeyer ? :)

Comment: From version 3.4.0, you can use [ko.onError](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/asynchronous-error-handling.html) for certain contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch block.

```
try {
    adddlert("Welcome guest!");
}
catch(err) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
}
```

And pass the error message to the user.

Comment: The problem is that it is the javascript library knockout that catches the error. 
I would rather not edit in that code (when the next update comes I don't want to edit again)

Comment: @AbhashUpadhyaya great , you was more fast than i :+1: